# Entity Framework 6 including only child records that have a specific value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to return a record set that includes child records that meet a specific data requirements. This is my base query, and in this case I am only trying to bring back children where the IsActive field is true.

```
var result = db.Projects
         .Include(p => p.Department)
         .Include(p => p.ProjectPhases.Where(pp =>pp.IsActive ))
         .Include(p => p.Notes)
         .AsQueryable<Project>();
```

This returns an error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Is there simple way to do this?

Comment: Filtered includes - one of the most requested EF features (with a lot of questions on SO). Not implemented even in the latest EF Core.

Comment: EF Code has [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters).

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform where clause inside of `Include`. Why don't you just try like this;

```
var result = db.Projects
         .Include(p => p.Department)
         .Include(p => p.ProjectPhases)
         .Include(p => p.Notes)
         .Where(x => x.ProjectPhases.Where(pp =>pp.IsActive))
         .AsQueryable<Project>();
```

Comment: I just found that the where clause 
   `.Where(p =>p.ProjectPhases.All(a=>a.IsActive) )` does exactly what I need.

Comment: This limits the `Projects`, not the `ProjectPhases`. It translates into some thing like `SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE ProjectID IN (SELECT ProjectID FROM ProjectPhases WHERE IsActive <>0)`

Answer (score 0):

Those `Include`s generate the joins, to filter out use the `Where` after the `Include` chain:

```
var result = db.Projects
         .Include(p => p.Department)
         .Include(p => p.ProjectPhases)
         .Include(p => p.Notes)
         .Where(it => it.ProjectPhases.All(a=>a.IsActive))
         .AsQueryable<Project>();
```